# using category to split up work in a UIViewController - how to reference parent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, categories

I read somewhere recently that if you have an exceptionally large view controller class, you might consider splitting it up into multiple categories based on the work being performed. I'm attempting to do that, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it properly. And, on top of that, I can't find any online sources on the practice.

So I have this view controller that has 5+ UIViews laid out in a UIScrollView. I'm trying to create a private category for each UIView and put any work for those views within the category, i.e. any programmatic visual work, button presses, etc. However, I need a reference to the parent object to change the visual values because all labels and buttons are defined on the parent object. I can't define them within the category, Xcode won't let me. It will only let me define button presses. I've already tried sending a weak copy of self to the category upon initialization, but using it didn't change the visual values of any of the labels or anything.

It's pretty imperative that I have access to other objects within the parent. If I don't, this is kind of a lost cause. So, is it a lost cause? or am i doing it wrong?

**within main class**

```
__weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
[_diaryViewController setupDietDiaryViewForController:weakSelf];
```

**within category**

```
- (void)setupDietDiaryViewForController:(PADashboardViewController *)mainDashboard {
  mainDashboard.chooseHungerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.4f];
  mainDashboard.chooseHungerView.layer.borderWidth = 0.4f;
  mainDashboard.chooseHungerView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A category is nothing more than an extension of the base class. In essence, you could place any code within a category at the bottom of the main file and it would work exactly the same. Commonly, programmers prefer to split functionality up into categories in an attempt to make the code more readable.

Since it's nothing more than an extension of the main functionality, there is no need to create a reference to the parent class. If you want to make variables available to the category, all you need to do is place the variables in the header file of the main file. When you call a category function, you'll want to do it as if the function was within the base file itself.

```
[self setupProgressView];
```

Make sure the function `setupProgressView` is not static (it should be defined with a - instead of a +).

and within the category itself, you access variables like so:

```
[self.chooseHungerButton changeTitle:@"New Title"];
[self.deviationButton changeTitle:@"New Title"];
```

If you're trying to shift IB functionality over to a category, you'll need to define the buttons/views/objects within the base file's header. After defining the variables, you can access them from the category. If you want to create a method call for the button, you can control-drag the button straight into the category's .m file.

Make sure you include the category's .h file in the base file before attempting to use any functions within.